# Systematic HTML tags validation

Tags: html, xhtml, validation, w3c-validation, tidy

Is there an offline tool that can verify whether certain tags possess particular attributes?

I'm looking for something that can verify that all:

- `form` tags have a `name` attribute.
- `div`, and `span` tags have at least an `id` or `class` attribute.

Does tidy have an obscure option where you could specify such things?

Comment: No, you'd probably have to build a script, or customize an existing validator solution. But do these rules really make general sense? What is your use case?

Comment: I'm trying to develop selenium tests on a website which has many empty divs that are nested. It makes difficult to get such elements by xpath. Would prefer clarify the website first but I need something to easily report them.

Comment: You want to verify that forms *do* have a name attribute? The specification says you should use id instead. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-FORM

Answer (score 3):

simply and quickly you can do your validations like this if jQuery is available on your page.

```
    $('form').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('name') === undefined) {
            alert('There is at least one form with no name.');
        }
    });
    $('div').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('id') === undefined) {
            alert('There is at least one div with no id.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Javascript wouldn't be the way to go, I need to validate my site with a crawler and get a report out of it.

Answer (score 1):

also this is a non-jQuery solution example

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i].getAttribute('id') == null) {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (flag) {
    alert('There is at least one div with no name.');
}
```